# iPhone Build custom monocolor image with clear area at fixed coords

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, cgcontext

So what I want to do is build an image the size of the device. The image should be all blue except for a circle at coords (x,y) with a radius of z that should be clear, where x,y,z are variables. I know I should use the CGContext I just don't know how to get it done.
Ani ideas?

Comment: if you just want to display this image , create a blue png image with the clear circle and set it in an image view ... or is there any specific need for you to 'create' such an image in your code... if not you are probably looking for help in photoshop/image editing and all the iOS tags wont help you much..

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html) for this. To be more precise, read up on [`CGContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950) and the functions used to manipulate them. There are plenty of tutorials for it out there, and Apple provides a lot of sample code as well.